# How do they set the clocks on spacecraft visiting several other planets?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, time, observers, space-travel

Scientists have sent spacecraft into distant space passing nearby other planets on the voyage.  How do they set the clocks to adjust for kinetic time dilation (special relativity) and gravitational time dilations (general relativity) as the craft pass nearby these other planets and then move out into deep space again?   Do the clocks change their amount of adjustment when near each planet and when in deep space?

Comment: This might be better suited to [the Space Exploration stackexchange](https://space.stackexchange.com/). \[P.S., You asked, "_How..?_" but how is trivial. It's just a [small matter of programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_matter_of_programming). OTOH, there are at least two interesting ways to go with your question. Option A: To what extent is it necessary to account for time dilation when navigating the spacecraft? and Part Deux: To what extent do communication protocols require such precise accounting for the difference between the spacecraft's proper time, and the time back home?]

Comment: P.P.S., Re, "Do the clocks change their amount of adjustment when..?" Sounds like you _might_ be imagining that they would change the rate at which the clock ticks. But that makes no sense. If you need to know the time with such precision, then you aren't going to build a clock with a knob that can be turned. You're going to use an atomic clock that ticks at an unalterable rate, and then you're going to keep track of the several cumulative offsets between the spacecraft's own proper time, and the time that you expect will be shown on clocks in the several other locations that you care about.

Comment: @SolomonSlow your second point is what I'm asking about.  Do they set the clocks on the craft to change so that they stay synchronized with Earth clocks, or do they just let it fly with an unchanging clock that would of course change as it moves near these different planets, and then adjust the receiving clock back on Earth to receive at the appropriate time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Relativistic effects are generally not an issue for current spacecraft; that is, the accuracy of clocks on typical spacecraft is not great enough to detect relativistic time dilation, with other sources of "drift" being greater. There are a very few exceptions (e.g. clocks in navigation systems such as GPS) but those are so far restricted to Earth orbital missions, and relativistic corrections are accounted for ahead of time: the clocks are adjusted to tick slower or faster as needed to stay in sync with the surface of the Earth. The first planned use of an atomic clock for a deep space mission appears to be on the VERITAS mission scheduled for 2028 [as described here](https://phys.org/news/2021-10-overtime-nasa-deep-space-atomic.html).

[This paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20010111035/downloads/20010111035.pdf) discusses the general principles of timekeeping for space missions. Generally speaking the spacecraft clocks are synchronized with the clocks at mission control, and the Earth (UTC) time is used for almost all purposes.

Comment: nice answer. The following is probably content for another question but I'm interested in how this would be handled if relativity DID matter. What if we had 3 planets A, B, and C under going relativistic velocity and acceleration with respect to each other and three ships X, Y, and Z travelling between them, and perhaps a black hole that the ships occasionally pass by. How would time keeping work in this case? It seems like all observers would need to keep track of the relative velocities and local gravitational fields observed by each other observer for all time to keep track.

Comment: @Jagerber48, Re, "...and perhaps a black hole..." The closest black hole candidates are all more than 1000 light years from Earth. Nobody currently is planning any mission to visit them. Just to put that number into perspective, there is a star named [Gliese 445](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gliese_445), which is merely 17 light years from Earth. The [Voyager 1 spacecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_1), launched in 1977, is expected to pass near that star in about 40,000 years from now.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised by the choice of UTC. If you only care about timestamps, there's no problem, but if you want to calculate time elapsed between two timestamps, the fact that minutes can sometimes have 59 or 61 seconds without any discernible pattern gets annoying really fast.